Mantras for self control?
What are some of the mantras which can give us some self control over our thoughts and compulses ?

Not exactly a mantra, but daily chanting of the Hanumān Chālisā does help inculcate discipline across many facets of life.

Is it an observatory fact?? @Madhur. If it truly is then I will start chanting the hanuman chalisa . Please clarify my doubt by either experiencial or scriptural reference. Thank you.

It is my personal observation/experience. As for scriptural reference, like many other Hindu scriptures, the Hanumān Chālisā itself lists the benefits of ritually reciting it towards the end. Do read it, with meaning.

Thank you very much @Madhur

You need to get diksha first
Kalarnav tantra restricts chanting mantras without dikha

However you can do naam japa and it is also beneficial for self control
